# Notation for summing over all cyclic permutations of three indices

Tags: summation, notation, index-notation

I have an expression which depends on three indices. For example, something like $\cos(\alpha_1 +\alpha_2-\alpha_3)$. Say I want to write the sum
$$\cos(\alpha_1 +\alpha_2-\alpha_3) + \cos(\alpha_3 +\alpha_1-\alpha_2) + \cos(\alpha_2 +\alpha_3-\alpha_1)$$
so that I get sum over all cyclic permutations of $1,2,3$. Is there a nice way to write such a sum with sigma notation? I could not come up with anything which was not very clumsy to write or read. I thought about maybe writing the sum over $i,i+1,i+2$ mod $3$, but this does not fit exactly what I want (for instance, since I cannot take the mod inside the sum, since it could contain real numbers).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can write this expression using *[cyclic sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum)* notation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\cos(\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3)}&=\cos(\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3)+\cos(\alpha_3+\alpha_1-\alpha_2)\\
&\qquad+\cos(\alpha_2+\alpha_3-\alpha_1)
\end{align*}
replacing the letters $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ systematically in a cyclic manner.